# Nginx to tomcat SSL connection | no cipher suites in common

Tags: tomcat, ssl, nginx, tls1.2

**Situation**
Nginx running on server A, tries to connect to Tomcat running on server B. Throws an SSL exception. Details below

**Logs on Nginx**

```
2017/08/22 17:19:09 [error] 13571#13571: *3 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure) while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: xx.xx.xx.xx, server: 10.228.AA.AA, request: "GET /openam/abc HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://10.228.BB.BB:8443/openam/", host: "AA.abc.com"
```

**SSL debug logs on Tomcat**

```
Using SSLEngineImpl.
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
http-nio-8443-exec-5, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 512
*** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1662107440 bytes = { 175, 73, 217, 55, 148, 110, 231, 238, 5, 15, 173, 203, 212, 145, 27, 37, 247, 30, 194, 85, 11, 238, 198, 156, 200, 246, 106, 53 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_SEED_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_SEED_CBC_SHA, TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_SEED_CBC_SHA, TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_SEED_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_SEED_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DH_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_IDEA_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension server_name, server_name: [type=host_name (0), value=BBB.abc.com]
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed, ansiX962_compressed_prime, ansiX962_compressed_char2]
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, secp521r1, secp384r1, secp256k1}
Unsupported extension type_35, data:
Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA512withRSA, Unknown (hash:0x6, signature:0x2), SHA512withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, Unknown (hash:0x5, signature:0x2), SHA384withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA256withDSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA224withRSA, SHA224withDSA, SHA224withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA, SHA1withECDSA
Unsupported extension type_15, data: 01
Unsupported extension type_21, data: 00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00
***
%% Initialized:  [Session-5, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL]
http-nio-8443-exec-5, fatal error: 40: no cipher suites in common
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common
%% Invalidated:  [Session-5, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL]
http-nio-8443-exec-5, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = handshake_failure
http-nio-8443-exec-5, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
http-nio-8443-exec-5, fatal: engine already closed.  Rethrowing javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common
http-nio-8443-exec-5, called closeOutbound()
http-nio-8443-exec-5, closeOutboundInternal()
```

**Nginx configs**

```
server {
    listen 443 default_server ssl;
    server_name AA;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/AA.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/pki/tls/private/AA.key;
    ########################################################################
    # from https://cipherli.st/                                            #
    # and https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/Strong_SSL_Security_On_nginx.html #
    ########################################################################

    ssl on;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    #ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_tickets off;
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    #resolver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 valid=300s;
    #resolver_timeout 5s;
    # Disable preloading HSTS for now.  You can use the commented out header line that includes
    # the "preload" directive if you understand the implications.
    #add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload";
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains";
    add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;

    ##################################
    # END https://cipherli.st/ BLOCK #
    ##################################

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;


    location /openam {
        proxy_pass https://BBB.com:8443/openam;
        proxy_ssl_server_name on;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
```

**Tomcat configs**

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
           maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" keystoreFile="/root/.keystore" keystorePass="changeit"/>
```

**Misc**

1. The certificate on both nginx and tomcat have the same hierarchy of
   certs starting from the org-level CA. Only the last cert is having a
   different common-name corresponding to the server.
2. The certificates on /etc/pki/tls/certs/aaa.com.pem looks like -

   ```
   -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
   sdfsdf
   -----END CERTIFICATE-----
   -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
   fgghj
   -----END CERTIFICATE-----
   -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
   sdsdfsd
   -----END CERTIFICATE-----
   ```
3. On tomcat, I used the command -

   ```
   keytool -import -alias my_common -trustcacerts -file /etc/pki/tls/certs/aaa.com.pem -storepass xxx -noprompt
   ```

   to import this pem file to the /root/.keystore keystore file.

**Versions**

- Nginx - nginx/1.10.3
- Tomcat - 8.0.43

Any suggestions on how I could fix this?

Comment: Redo the import without `-trustcacerts`. You didn't import the private key. List the keystore for proof.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @EJP. The certs and the private keys needed to be exported to a pk12 format and imported to a keystore. That did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply @EJP. The certs and the private keys needed to be exported to a pk12 format and imported to a keystore. That did the trick!